# What does perl's int(-M $file) do?

Tags: perl, file

I'm looking over some older perl code and I can see that someone is comparing the timestamps on various files in a directory using:

```
int(-M $filename);
```

What does this do exactly? I looked at the `int()` entry in the documentation and I can't find anything about the `-M` flag.

Comment: it's one of the [file test operators](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node69.html), and the int() is just typecasting that result to an integer.

Comment: To be precise, it's `Script start time minus file modification time, in days`.

Comment: `perldoc -f -M` (or see the [online version](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html))

Comment: To further clarify, `-M` is not a "flag" for `int()`. It's like `int(age_of($bob))` might round down Bob's age to the nearest integer. `age_of` is not a "flag" for `int()` - instead the output of `age_of` becomes the input of `int()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a file test operator [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

> - `-X FILEHANDLE`
> - `-X EXPR`
> - `-X DIRHANDLE`
> - `-X`
>
>   A file test, where `X` is one of the letters listed below. This unary operator takes one argument, either a filename, a filehandle, or a dirhandle, and tests the associated file to see if something is true about it. If the argument is omitted, tests `$_` , except for `-t` , which tests `STDIN`. Unless otherwise documented, it returns `1` for true and `''` for false. If the file doesn't exist or can't be examined, it returns `undef` and sets `$!` (errno). Despite the funny names, precedence is the same as any other named unary operator. The operator may be any of:
>
>   ```
>   ...
>   31.  -M  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.
>   ```